# Traffic doesn't transmit over l2tp/ipsec vpn tunnel in Sierra [Software, VPN]

Tags: macos, vpn

I set up a vpn server on VPS, using strongswan, l2tpd, and ppp. Just use PSK to do authentication and no cert.

I connect the VPN on my MAC successfully. But I noticed that all the traffic on my MAC was NOT transmitted over that VPN tunnel even when I enabled "Send all traffic over VPN connection". Does someone know why? My macOS is Sierra.

As I understand, if I connected to a VPN, the first line in the 'traceroute' should be the VPN ip, am I right?

But on my mac, it will return the same result when I do 'traceroute www.google.com' no matter with or without the VPN connection, why?
Please see the result:

```
bash-3.2$ traceroute www.google.com
traceroute to www.google.com (216.58.197.228), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.31.1 (192.168.31.1)  1.763 ms  1.562 ms  0.943 ms #<-- My router IP
 2  114.243.48.1 (114.243.48.1)  7.755 ms  2.452 ms  4.339 ms  #<-- My Network SP
 3  * * *
 4  61.51.169.217 (61.51.169.217)  4.465 ms
    123.126.8.169 (123.126.8.169)  3.195 ms
    124.65.59.105 (124.65.59.105)  6.833 ms
 5  124.65.194.73 (124.65.194.73)  9.057 ms
    202.96.12.1 (202.96.12.1)  4.872 ms
    124.65.194.33 (124.65.194.33)  3.335 ms
 6  219.158.7.226 (219.158.7.226)  32.817 ms *
    219.158.8.86 (219.158.8.86)  53.460 ms
```

Comment: We need to know what are the IP address ranges on the remote side, and are they distinct from the address ranges on your side.  A VPN tunnel of any kind basically acts as a TCP/IP router or a switch.  The `netstat -nr` command should show you your entire routing table which determines how, and through what [virtual] network interface, the traffic is being routed.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't actually know whether "route all traffic through the VPN" causes the software to act as a _router,_ or as a _switch._  (The latter "scoops up everything," not just TCP/IP, e.g. Bonjour auto-discovery messages.)  If it's a switch, you might not see it in the routing tables.  I'm actually not 150% sure since I use OpenVPN all the time, and, only as a router.  So, there will be slight differences that I don't routinely see.

Comment: The reason why I talked about "IP address ranges" is that, as with any router situation, the addresses in each area of the subnet must be distinct, so that a routing rule _can_ be created everywhere which will direct the traffic to the right place.  Commonly, everyone uses `192.168.0.x` but "everyone" can't do that when you're routing subnets together (by any technology at all).  One area might use `.1.x`, another `.2.x` and so on.